# Can I replay the festival in New Donk City?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

After getting Pauline's band together, the final objective for New Donk City is *[A Traditional Festival](http://www.ign.com/wikis/super-mario-odyssey/A_Traditional_Festival)*. The entire city holds a giant festival while the band plays "Jump Up, Super Star".

The festival was one of my favorite parts of the game. Is there any way to replay the New Donk City festival?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can!

All you need to do is return to New Donk City and re-enter city hall. There will be a man in the left corner who you can speak to which lets you replay the festival.

Not that I think it needs much more explaining, but [here's a video showing exactly who to talk to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CabFz7yhyQ).

Comment: This is especially useful because there are 2 Power Moons to be found during the festival.